# WG3526 modem can't connect to 4G/LTE with OpenWRT

Tags: router, openwrt, mobile-devices

I have a client with a WG3526 4G/LTE modem with a sim card slot.

I had to change the firmware so I can get detailed bandwidth usage.

My issue is since I installed the generic version of OpenWRT, the modem can't connect to mobile network anymore.

I know I need to install a new module in OpenWRT but I can't find which one.

I need help to find the required module and maybe to install it.

Answer (score 0):

did you found a solution, but for me it´s also not working.

I found those threads:

https://forum.openwrt.org/t/zbt-wg3526-sim-card-not-working/135981
https://openwrt.org/toh/zbtlink/wg2626#installation

Please be informed, I just want to create only a comment, but I was not allowed to do it (less reputation)